# Create new SubCA certificate fails with NTE_PROV_TYPE_NOT_DEF

Tags: windows, certificate, pki, private-key, cryptography

I am trying to manually create a key and CSR for a new Windows AD CS Enterprise Subordinate CA (Windows Server 2019).

I'd like to store the key in the modern *Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider*.

It fails with `Provider type not defined. 0x80090017 (-2146893801 NTE_PROV_TYPE_NOT_DEF)`.

The command I use is: `certreq.exe -new C:\requestconfig.inf C:\certificate.req`

The `C:\requestconfig.inf` file is this:

```
[Version]
Signature= "$Windows NT$"


[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=My Subordinate CA"

HashAlgorithm = sha256
KeyAlgorithm = RSA
KeyLength = 2048

ProviderName = "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider"
KeyContainer = "My Subordinate CA"
ExportableEncrypted = true
MachineKeySet = true
RequestType = PKCS10
SuppressDefaults = true
SecurityDescriptor = "D:P(A;OICI;0xd01f01ff;;;BA)(A;OICI;0xd01f01ff;;;SY)"


[RequestAttributes]
CertificateTemplate = SubCA


[Extensions]
2.5.29.15 = "{critical}{hex}03020186" ; Key Usage (critical): Digital Signature, Certificate Signing, CRL Signing
2.5.29.19 = "{critical}{text}ca=1&pathlength=1" ; Basic Constraints (critical)
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.1 = "{hex}020100" ; CA Version V0.0
```

### Troubleshooting Steps

I checked that the CSP is valid by running `certutil -csplist`:

```
[...]
Provider Name: Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider
Provider Type: 1 - PROV_RSA_FULL

Provider Name: Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider

Provider Name: Microsoft Passport Key Storage Provider
[...]
```

It does not have a provider type, but nonetheless, I added `ProviderType = 0` and `ProviderType = 1` to the config, to no avail.

I was able to use a very similar config to create my root certificate:

```
[Version]
Signature= "$Windows NT$"


[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=My Root CA"

HashAlgorithm = sha256
KeyAlgorithm = RSA
KeyLength = 4096
;KeyUsage = CERT_DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_KEY_USAGE | CERT_KEY_CERT_SIGN_KEY_USAGE | CERT_CRL_SIGN_KEY_USAGE

ProviderName = "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider"
KeyContainer = "My Root CA"
ExportableEncrypted = true
MachineKeySet = true
RequestType = Cert
SuppressDefaults = true
SecurityDescriptor = "D:P(A;OICI;0xd01f01ff;;;BA)(A;OICI;0xd01f01ff;;;SY)


[Extensions]
2.5.29.15 = {critical}{hex}03020186 ; Key Usage (critical): Digital Signature, Certificate Signing, CRL Signing
2.5.29.19 = {critical}{text}ca=1&pathlength=None ; Basic Constraints (critical)
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.1 = {hex}020100 ; CA Version V0.0
```

The main difference is that with this config, I create a key and certificate instead of a key and CSR. The differences are: `RequestType` is `Cert` and not `PKCS10` and it does not have the `RequestAttributes` section. This config did not fail with `NTE_PROV_TYPE_NOT_DEF`.

What is causing the sudden failure with the config for my sub CA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add:

```
KeySpec=0
```

to `NewRequest` section. certreq defaults to `AT_EXCHANGE` while CNG providers do not support KeySpec.

Just out of curiosity, why you do not use ADCS CA installation wizard to generate the CA request?

Comment: Two reasons. (1) It adds the EKU of Client and Server Authentication, which should not be part of a CA certificate, in my opinion. I know that the RFC does permits an EKU. This is a design choice. (2) To add Basic Constraints path length **and** mark the extension as critical.

Comment: Reason (1) is simply incorrect. CA installation wizard does not add any EKU by default. You can add Basic Constraints settings using CAPolicy.inf file. I would strongly recommend to use ADCS CA installation wizard instead of certreq workaround.

Comment: Seems you are right with (1). I probably made a mistake setting up my test lab. As for (2), the docs state that all settings defined in the file [are applied to a root CA certificate and all certificates issued by the root CA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/core-network-guide/cncg/server-certs/prepare-the-capolicy-inf-file). So when I add the critical flag to the KeyUsage extension, this will always also be critical on any issued certificate? So I should use that setting and that file on the root CA instead of the subordinate CA that also issues end-entity certs?

Comment: You should set critical flag in all certificates explicitly. For CA certs via CAPolicy.inf and via request/cert template setting for end entity certs.